# Huge error trying to decompile Minecraft 1.12 with MCP

Tags: minecraft

I have been trying to use MCP to decompile the Minecraft Source code to an eclipse workspace. I am using mcp940 to decompile Minecraft 1.12. When I run the BATCH file `decompile.bat`, it gives me a huge pile of errors. I was following a video tutorial linked at the bottom of this question, and the host skipped this step entirely. The eclipse workspace still loads and has all of the code, but said code is riddled with errors. When I try to run `Start`, the class with the main method, I am given the following error message:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The video tutorial links to another video tutorial (also linked down below) about fixing the realms jar version. I fixed this issue, yet it seems that that issue was only one of many.
After fixing this part, I attempted to run it and yet still received the same error message.

Here is the console's output:

```
== MCP 9.40 (data: 9.40, client: 1.12, server: 1.12) ==
> Searching for javac.exe in C:\Program Files
"scalac" is not found on the PATH.  Scala files will not be recompiled
# found ff, ff patches, srgs, name csvs, doc csvs, param csvs, astyle, astyle config, rg, ss
Looking in C:\Users\Calvin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions for mc installs... OK
Copying assets... OK
Parsing JSON file... OK
Looking for minecraft main jar... Not found
Copying minecraft main jar... OK
> Checking libraries...
        Copying library jinput... OK
        Copying library icu4j-core-mojang... OK
        Copying library httpcore... OK
        Copying library log4j-api... OK
        Copying library commons-lang3... OK
        Copying library jna... OK
        Copying library lwjgl-platform-natives-windows... OK
        Copying library libraryjavasound... OK
        Copying library jopt-simple... OK
        Copying library text2speech... OK
        Copying library guava... OK
        Copying library oshi-core... OK
        Copying library httpclient... OK
        Copying library commons-compress... OK
        Copying library text2speech-natives-windows... OK
        Copying library fastutil... OK
        Copying library platform... OK
        Copying library codecjorbis... OK
        Copying library soundsystem... OK
        Copying library librarylwjglopenal... OK
        Copying library lwjgl_util... OK
        Copying library commons-codec... OK
        Copying library jutils... OK
        Copying library patchy... OK
        Copying library commons-logging... OK
        Copying library lwjgl... OK
        Copying library commons-io... OK
        Copying library realms... OK
        Copying library authlib... OK
        Copying library gson... OK
        Copying library jinput-platform-natives-windows... OK
        Copying library codecwav... OK
        Copying library log4j-core... OK
        Copying library netty-all... OK
> Checking Natives...
        Extracting native lwjgl.dll... OK
        Extracting native OpenAL32.dll... OK
        Extracting native jinput-dx8_64.dll... OK
        Extracting native SAPIWrapper_x86.dll... OK
        Extracting native jinput-wintab.dll... OK
        Extracting native jinput-dx8.dll... OK
        Extracting native jinput-raw.dll... OK
        Extracting native OpenAL64.dll... OK
        Extracting native SAPIWrapper_x64.dll... OK
        Extracting native jinput-raw_64.dll... OK
        Extracting native lwjgl64.dll... OK
> Copying jsr305-3.0.1.jar to Libraries
> Copying jsr305-3.0.1-sources.jar to Libraries
== Decompiling client using fernflower ==
> Creating SRGs
> Applying SpecialSource
> Applying MCInjector
> Creating renamed srg
> Filtering classes
> Decompiling
> Unpacking jar
> Copying sources
> Generating package-info files
> Applying fernflower fixes
> Applying patches
'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\advancements\PlayerAdvance#'
==================

'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\client\renderer\entity\RenderManager#'
==================

'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\util\math\Cartesian.jav#'
==================

'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\client\util\SearchTree.ja#'
==================

'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\client\renderer\block\statemap\StateMap.java#'
==================

'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\client\gui\GuiSnooper.ja#'
==================

'runtime\bin\applydiff.exe -p1 -u -i ..\..\temp\temp.patch -d src\minecraft' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND ==

2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file 'net\minecraft\block\state\pattern\BlockStateMat#'
==================

> Cleaning comments
- Done in 2605.28 seconds
== Reformating client ==
> Cleaning sources
> Replacing OpenGL constants
> Reformating sources
- Done in 118.96 seconds
== Updating client ==
> Adding javadoc
> Renaming sources
- Done in 126.23 seconds
!! Missing server jar file. Aborting !!
== Recompiling client ==
> Cleaning bin
> Recompiling
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\javac" -Xlint:-options -deprecation -g -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -classpath "jars\versions\1.12\1.12.jar;lib;lib\*;jars\libraries\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.1\jsr305-3.0.1.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;jars\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;jars\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;jars\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;jars\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;jars\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3-natives-windows.jar;jars\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;jars\libraries\com\mojang\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar;jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;jars\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.17\realms-1.10.17.jar;jars\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar;jars\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;jars\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar" -sourcepath src\minecraft -d bin\minecraft @temp\java_src_client.txt' failed : 1

== ERRORS FOUND in JAVA CODE ==


            this.block.addCollisionBoxToList(this, worldIn, pos, p_185908_3_, p_185908_4_, p_185908_5_, p_185908_6_);
                      ^

src\minecraft\net\minecraft\block\state\pattern\BlockStateMatcher.java:64: error: incompatible types: inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        return predicate.apply(blockState.getValue(property));
                        ^

    equality constraints: T#2
    upper bounds: CAP#1,Comparable<T#1>
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in method <T#1>getValue(IProperty<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in method <T#2>matches(IBlockState,IProperty<T#2>,Predicate<?>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\entity\RenderManager.java:266: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
            return renderplayer != null ? renderplayer : this.playerRenderer;
                                          ^

    RenderPlayer cannot be converted to Render<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Entity declared in method <T>getEntityRenderObject(Entity)
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\entity\RenderManager.java:266: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
            return renderplayer != null ? renderplayer : this.playerRenderer;
                                                             ^

    RenderPlayer cannot be converted to Render<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Entity declared in method <T>getEntityRenderObject(Entity)
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\GuiIngame.java:1304: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to IChatListener
        for (IChatListener ichatlistener : (List)this.field_191743_I.get(p_191742_1_))
                                           ^

src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\util\SearchTree.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
            this.field_194045_b.func_194057_a(p_194039_1_, p_194039_2_.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
                                              ^

  symbol:   variable p_194039_1_
  location: class SearchTree<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class SearchTree
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\util\SearchTree.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
            this.field_194044_a.func_194057_a(p_194041_1_, p_194041_2_.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
                                              ^

  symbol:   variable p_194041_1_
  location: class SearchTree<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class SearchTree
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\util\SearchTree.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
            this.field_194044_a.func_194057_a(p_194041_1_, p_194041_2_.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
                                                                      ^

  symbol:   method toLowerCase(Locale)
  location: variable p_194041_2_ of type Object
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\GuiSnooper.java:51: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,String>
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : (new TreeMap(this.mc.getPlayerUsageSnooper().getCurrentStats())).entrySet())
                                                                                                                    ^

src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\GuiSnooper.java:59: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Entry<String,String>
            for (Entry<String, String> entry1 : (new TreeMap(this.mc.getIntegratedServer().getPlayerUsageSnooper().getCurrentStats())).entrySet())
                                                                                                                                               ^

src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\recipebook\GuiButtonRecipeTab.java:33: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to RecipeList
        for (RecipeList recipelist : (List)RecipeBookClient.field_194086_e.get(this.field_193921_u))
                                     ^

src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\block\model\ModelBakery.java:492: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ModelResourceLocation
            for (ModelResourceLocation modelresourcelocation1 : (Collection)entry.getValue())
                                                                ^

src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\block\statemap\StateMap.java:57: error: incompatible types: Comparable cannot be converted to T
        return p_187490_1_.getName((Comparable)p_187490_2_.remove(this.name));
                                   ^

  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>removeName(IProperty<T>,Map<IProperty<?>,Comparable<?>>)
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\resources\FolderResourcePack.java:83: error: reference to listFiles is ambiguous
            for (File file2 : file1.listFiles(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY))
                                   ^

  both method listFiles(FilenameFilter) in File and method listFiles(FileFilter) in File match
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\util\math\Cartesian.java:57: error: incompatible types: inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
            return Arrays.asList(p_apply_1_);
                                ^

    equality constraints: T#2
    lower bounds: Object
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>asList(T#1...)
    T#2 extends Object declared in class GetList
15 errors
100 warnings
==================

Initial client recompile failed, correct source then run updatemd5

Press any key to continue . . .
```

NOTE: I had to delete a bunch of depreciation warnings to fit this in.

This was supposed to just live run Minecraft in debug mode.

Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoZ8AvQ

Realms Jar Fix Tutorial: https://youtu.be/17FQl1xpOF0﻿

Comment: @Draco18s this is MCP, not Forge.

Comment: IMO one shouldn't be using MCP directly. Either use Forge or Bukkit (or whatever the Bukkit replacement is called these days). Not-using these existing apis leads you down a road of either: incompatible mods or violating the eula (possibly even violating copyright).

Comment: @Draco18s do not worry, I am just fiddling around for now. If I decide to make mods, I will heed your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue and I'll put it here for anyone sharing my problem. I was using JDK 10, and that caused a lot of version errors. I downloaded JDK and JRE 8, adjusted my system variables to account for it, deleted the failure MCP eclipse workspaces, redownloaded MCP and once again ran decompile.bat this time with Java 8. It worked perfectly.

Here is the download link for the version of Java 8 I used:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html